# adding options to select on focus IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to lazy load options into a select with jquery. This code works in all browsers I've tested except IE9. (IE7, IE8, FF, Chrome all work)

```
function LazyLoadOptionsIntoSelect($select, options) {
        //get current option
        var selectedOptionVal = $select.val();
        var selectedOptionDisplay = $select.find("option:selected").text();

        //repopulate options
        if (selectedOptionDisplay === "--Select a File--"
                || selectedOptionDisplay === "----------") {
            $select.html("");

            $("<option>").val("").text("--Select a File--")
                        .appendTo($select);
        }
        else {
            $select.html($("option:selected", $select));
            $("<option>").val("").text("----------")
                        .appendTo($select);
        }
        $.each(options, function () {
            var item = this;
            $("<option>").attr("name", function () { return item.display; })
                    .val(item.value)
                    .text(item.display)
                    .appendTo($select);
        });

        //select previous val
        $select.val(selectedOptionVal);
    }

    $(document).on("focus", ".html-select", function () {
        LazyLoadOptionsIntoSelect($(this), HtmlOptions);
    });
    $(document).on("focus", ".txt-select", function () {
        LazyLoadOptionsIntoSelect($(this), TxtOptions);
    });
    $(document).on("focus", ".xml-select", function () {
        LazyLoadOptionsIntoSelect($(this), XmlOptions);
    });
```

I've been trying to solve this for hours but nothing is working.. any solutions or do I need to write a different way to load options in IE9?

options is an array of objects containing value, and display.

This works in simpler use cases, but this apparently is too much for Microsoft to handle. <_<

Comment: Do you get any errors in the IE dev console?

Comment: I wish, then I'd have something to go by. When I click the down arrow, it is cleared, almost like it displays the dropdown before the options are added. If I look in the html I can see all of the options are there, just ie9 doesn't want to show them.

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.7, tried upgrading to 1.7.1 but the same problem occurred.

Comment: Can you post your generated HTML and what the values for HtmlOptions, TxtOptions, and XmlOptions are?

Comment: turns out redrawing the element was all it took

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of fiddling, I tried changing the css to see if redrawing the element worked. It did.

```
$(document).on("focus", ".html-select", function () {
        LazyLoadOptionsIntoSelect($(this), HtmlOptions);
        if ( $("body").hasClass("ie9") )
        {
            $(this).width($(this).width());
        }
    });
```